# Collective name for source and target

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

The context: I have 2 databases. The *source* database where I retrieve data and the *target* database where I insert data.

What is the collective name I can use for *source* and *target* in this context? *Target* can also be called *destination*.

Comment: They are both *databases*.

Comment: @MickSharpe I'm looking for something else. You are correct that both are can be called databases. But what if I change the context to say `source file` and `target file`.

Comment: I was just being facetious. This might be a good question for [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) (since I'm right out of ideas).

Comment: A graph theoretician would probably be happy to call them both *end-points* or *terminals*, but in English, both of those sound like *destination*.

Comment: Are they the *transfer endpoints*, *transfer pair*?

Comment: @Scott both also sound like `source`. but I don't want to use either `source` or `destination` because either one can be called that. Although, `endpoint` is a very good suggestion

Comment: @Jim It seems that I can use `endpoint`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Endpoint*** may work:

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endpoint):
>
>   either of two points or values that mark the ends of a line segment or interval
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endpoint):
>
>   either of the two nodes of a graph;
>     either of two extreme points on a line segment

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question while developing an application dealing with data transfers from and to multiple sources and destinations. After reading this thread, the term 'repository' came to my mind. The spring-data project, providing an abstraction to different data sources and targets, is also using it. Another term I have seen is use is 'store', but I think 'repository' is less ambiguous.